# QMediaPlayer не хочет воспроизводить трек?

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, qmediaplayer

Я пытаюсь разобраться с модулем `QMultiMedia()` в *PyQt5*.
Я хочу воспроизвести трек, но он попросту не воспроизводится, 
хотя я соединил его со слотом `play()`.

Может быть тут есть люди, знающие этот модуль?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from os.path import expanduser


class PlayListModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    Title, ColumnCount = range(2)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlayListModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_playlist = None

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.m_playlist.mediaCount() if self.m_playlist is not None and not parent.isValid() else 0

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.ColumnCount if not parent.isValid() else 0

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column) if \
            self.m_playlist is not None and not parent.isValid() \
            and row >= 0 and row < self.m_playlist.mediaCount() \
            and 0 <= column < self.ColumnCount else QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, child):
        return QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == self.Title:
                location = self.m_playlist.media(index.row()).canonicalUrl()
                return QFileInfo(location.path()).fileName()

            return self.m_data[index]
        return None

    def playlist(self):
        return self.m_playlist

    def setPlaylist(self, playlist):
        if self.m_playlist is not None:
            self.m_playlist.mediaAboutToBeInserted.disconnect(
                self.beginInsertItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaInserted.disconnect(self.endInsertItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaAboutToBeRemoved.disconnect(
                self.beginRemoveItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaRemoved.disconnect(self.endRemoveItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaChanged.disconnect(self.changeItems)

        self.beginResetModel()
        self.m_playlist = playlist

        if self.m_playlist is not None:
            self.m_playlist.mediaAboutToBeInserted.connect(
                self.beginInsertItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaInserted.connect(self.endInsertItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaAboutToBeRemoved.connect(
                self.beginRemoveItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaRemoved.connect(self.endRemoveItems)
            self.m_playlist.mediaChanged.connect(self.changeItems)

        self.endResetModel()

    def beginInsertItems(self, start, end):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), start, end)

    def endInsertItems(self):
        self.endInsertRows()

    def beginRemoveItems(self, start, end):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), start, end)

    def endRemoveItems(self):
        self.endRemoveRows()

    def changeItems(self, start, end):
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(start, 0),
                              self.index(end, self.ColumnCount))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setVolume(70)
        self.buttonPlay.clicked.connect(self.player.play)
        self.action_3.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        self.player.setVolume(70)

        self.model = PlayListModel()
        self.model.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.listTracks.setModel(self.model)
        self.listTracks.setCurrentIndex(
            self.model.index(self.playlist.currentIndex(), 0)
        )

    def open_file(self):
        fileChoosen = QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(self, 'Open Music File',
                                                 expanduser('~'),
                                                 'Audio (*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav)',
                                                 '*.mp3 *.ogg *.wav')
        if fileChoosen != None:
            self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(fileChoosen[0]))

def my_excepthook(type, value, tback):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
        window, "CRITICAL ERROR", str(value),
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel
    )

    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tback)

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Парсер seasonvar с QMediaPlayer: https://github.com/gil9red/grab_seasonvar/blob/5d650b999180fa7183f559e5bd4eb72bbd6619fa/gui.py#L251 подобное для аудиозаписей вк: https://github.com/gil9red/audio_player_vk/blob/6c03176abdd4b4bd13edde73a5b1361326df9211/audio_player_page.py#L258 пример простого воспроизведение без gui: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7695cdb024058aed290e4dc39077fa2794eb935d/play_sound__pyqt5/main.py#L23 / https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/play_mp3__pyqt5__qmediaplayer/play.py#L17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример невозможно воспроизвести, т.к. нет модуля `MainWindow.py`.

Но если вам хочется послушать музыку, вот вам один из вариантов Playera.

```
import sys
import os
import configparser
import random
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *

class MyMusicApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.Play_Pause, self.Preview_Next, self.mp3_url = True, False, ''

    def initUI(self):
        self.SongList = []
        self.player   = QMediaPlayer()

        self.lb1 = QLabel('00:00', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lb2 = QLabel('00:00', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.qsl = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)  
        self.qsl.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.SetPlayPosition)
        self.btn_play      = QPushButton('Воспроизведение', self, clicked=self.MusicPlay)       
        self.btn_preview   = QPushButton('Предыдущая песня', self, clicked=self.MusicPreview)   
        self.btn_next      = QPushButton('Следующая песня',self, clicked=self.MusicNext)
        self.btn_openmusic = QPushButton('Выберите папку с музыкой', self, clicked=self.OpenMusic)        
        self.lw = QListWidget(itemDoubleClicked=self.MouseDoubleClick) 

        if os.path.exists('Setting.ini'):
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read("Setting.ini")
            PATH   = config.get('Music', 'PATH')
            self.AddListItems(PATH)
        # Создайте раскрывающийся список, чтобы изменить режим воспроизведения музыки
        self.cmb = QComboBox()  
        self.cmb.addItem('Последовательное воспроизведение')
        self.cmb.addItem('Oдин цикл')
        self.cmb.addItem('Случайная игра')

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.PlayMode)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        # Схема сетки
        grid = QGridLayout(self)   
        grid.addWidget(self.lw,  0, 0, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lb1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.qsl, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.lb2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_preview,  2, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_play,     2, 1, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_next,     2, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.cmb,          3, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_openmusic,4, 0, 1, 3)

    def SetPlayPosition(self):
        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())

    def PlayMode(self):
        if self.Play_Pause==False:
            self.qsl.setMinimum(0)
            self.qsl.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
            self.qsl.setValue(self.qsl.value() + 1000)
        self.lb1.setText(time.strftime('%M:%S',time.localtime(self.player.position()/1000)))
        self.lb2.setText(time.strftime('%M:%S', time.localtime(self.player.duration() / 1000)))

        if self.player.position()==self.player.duration() and self.player.duration()!=0 and self.cmb.currentIndex()==0 and self.Play_Pause==False:
            if self.lw.count() == 0:
                return
            self.MusicNext()
        elif self.player.position()==self.player.duration() and self.player.duration()!=0 and self.cmb.currentIndex()==1 and self.Play_Pause==False:
            if self.lw.count() == 0:
                return
            self.Preview_Next = True
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.qsl.setValue(0)
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False
        elif self.player.position()==self.player.duration() and self.player.duration()!=0 and self.cmb.currentIndex()==2 and self.Play_Pause==False:
            if self.lw.count() == 0:
                return
            self.Preview_Next = True
            rand=random.randint(0, self.lw.count() - 1)
            self.lw.setCurrentRow(rand)
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[rand][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.qsl.setValue(0)
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False

    def OpenMusic(self):
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
                        self, 
                        "Выбрать папку с музыкой", 
                        os.getcwd(), 
                        QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        )  
        if directory:                          
            self.AddListItems(directory)
            self.mp3_url = ''
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.lb1.setText('00:00')
            self.lb2.setText('00:00')
            self.qsl.setSliderPosition(0)
            self.Play_Pause = True

    def AddListItems(self, directory):
        self.lw.clear()
        # Запишите музыкальный каталог в файл конфигурации для следующего удобного использования
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("Setting.ini")
        if not os.path.exists('Setting.ini'):
            config.add_section("Music")
        config.set("Music", "PATH", directory)
        config.write(open("Setting.ini", "w"))

        for songname in os.listdir(directory):
            if '.mp3' in songname:
                Song=[songname,(directory+'\\'+songname).replace('\\','/')]
                self.SongList.append(Song)
                self.lw.addItem(Song[0])
        self.lw.setCurrentRow(0)
        if not self.SongList:                 
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]

    # Дважды щелкните, чтобы воспроизвести музыку
    def MouseDoubleClick(self):
        print("  7 MouseDoubleClick")
        self.qsl.setValue(0)
        self.Preview_Next = True
        self.mp3_url      = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
        self.MusicPlay()
        self.Preview_Next = False

    def Message(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self,"Сообщение", "В настоящее время нет музыки.")

    # Воспроизведение и пауза
    def MusicPlay(self):
        if self.lw.count()==0:
            self.Message()
            return

        if self.player.isAudioAvailable()==False:
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))

        if self.Play_Pause==True or self.Preview_Next==True:
            self.player.play()
            self.Play_Pause=False
            self.btn_play.setText('Пауза')
        elif self.Play_Pause==False and self.Preview_Next==False:
            self.player.pause()
            self.Play_Pause=True
            self.btn_play.setText('Воспроизведение')

    # Предыдущая песня
    def MusicPreview(self):
        self.qsl.setValue(0)
        if self.lw.count()==0:
            self.Message()
            return

        if self.lw.currentRow()!=0:
            self.lw.setCurrentRow(self.lw.currentRow()-1)
            self.Preview_Next = True
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False
        else:
            self.lw.setCurrentRow(self.lw.count() - 1)
            self.Preview_Next = True
            self.mp3_url = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False

    # Следующая песня
    def MusicNext(self):
        self.qsl.setValue(0)
        if self.lw.count()==0:
            self.Message()
            return

        if self.lw.currentRow() != self.lw.count()-1:
            self.lw.setCurrentRow(self.lw.currentRow()+1)
            self.Preview_Next = True
            self.mp3_url      = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False
        else:
            self.lw.setCurrentRow(0)
            self.Preview_Next = True
            self.mp3_url      = self.SongList[self.lw.currentRow()][1]
            self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.mp3_url)))
            self.MusicPlay()
            self.Preview_Next = False


if __name__=='__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    w    = MyMusicApp()
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("myicon.ico"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
    w.setWindowIcon(icon)
    w.setWindowTitle('Музыкальный проигрыватель.')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что делать, если даже в вашем примере не проигрывается трек?
Он попросту не воспроизводится.

Comment: @marbl3 т.е. вы сформировали плейлист, затем нажали 'Воспроизведение' или сделали 'DoubleClick' по выбранному файлу (например формата .mp3) и что происходит ?

Comment: я выбрал папку с музыкой. Даблкликом нажал на первый и трек не проигрывается. Ничего не происходит. Я брал плееры других разработчиков, та же участь. Не знаю как это пофиксить.

Comment: @S.Nick не подскажете, для чего в этом коде нужны "пустые" return'ы? Я говорю о ситуации, когда в методе `PlayMode` за `return` ничего не следует

Comment: @MAXIM045 выход из функции (и передача данных в то место, откуда она была вызвана), выполняется оператором `return`. т.е. если мы поймали, какое-то условие, после которого нам ничего не надо делать (в данной функции) мы пишем  `return` и таким образом, как бы прерывает выполнение функции и выходим из нее.

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо, понял :)

Comment: @S.Nick Не подскажете, почему даблклик на композицию в списке песен сопровождается каким-то электронным звуком? Я разбираю код и не могу понять, где он вызывается

Comment: @MAXIM045 метод `MouseDoubleClick`  вызывается - `self.lw = QListWidget(itemDoubleClicked=self.MouseDoubleClick)`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked

Comment: @S.Nick про этот метод уже смотрел:) Я не могу найти источник звукового сопровождения даблклика. Думал, что легко смогу его отключить

Comment: @S.Nick я не уточнил - звуковой сигнал происходит и при нажатии на кнопки следующая/придыдущая песня. Как я понял, звук вызывает метод `MusicPlay`