# PyQt5 считывание mp3

Tags: python, pyqt5, mp3, qlistwidget, qmediaplayer

Я не понимаю работу `listwidget`, мне нужно что бы при нажатии на элемент списка, в котором выводятся возможные **`mp3`** в директории,  срабатывала функция, которая проиграет музыку (например через **`pyglet`** or **`pygame-mixer`**)

У меня никак не получается реализовать **`mp3 плеер`**. 
Весь код на pastebin - https://pastebin.com/PzFrRWCa

Часть кода с элементами и функцией.

````
     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item")) #Элементы, пришло в голову что можно воспользоваться такой структурой
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)                     #Но я всё равно не знаю как привязать элемент к файлу и как сделать открытие файла.
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.itemlist = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', ] #список из элементов
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.itemlist)
        
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
    def onClicked(self, item): #При нажатии на элемент срабатывает функция и выводит "0" 
        print('0')```
````

Comment: Приложил класс с реализацией ваших требований

Comment: DaYa sorry, вам не нужен ни `pyglet`,  ни `pygame-mixer`. В PyQt практический все есть, вам нужен `QMediaPlayer`. Вот вам приме того, что вы хотите реализовать - изучайте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038037/pyqt5-qmediaplayer-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba/1038204#1038204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Обновил класс `MainWindow`
2. Импортировал библиотеку `pygame`
3. Реализовал плеер

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushbutton_stop = QPushButton('Стоп', self)
        
        self.pushbutton_pause = QPushButton('Пауза', self)
        
        self.pushbutton_remove = QPushButton('Продолжить', self)
        
        self.itemlist = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', ] #список из элементов
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.itemlist)
        
        self.pushbutton_stop.clicked.connect(self.clickstop)
        self.pushbutton_stop.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: red;}')
        self.pushbutton_stop.move(150,0)
        
        self.pushbutton_pause.clicked.connect(self.clickpause)
        self.pushbutton_pause.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: yellow;}')
        self.pushbutton_pause.move(250,0)
        
        self.pushbutton_remove.clicked.connect(self.clickremove)
        self.pushbutton_remove.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: green;}')
        self.pushbutton_remove.move(250, 0)
        
        self.pushbutton_stop.hide()
        self.pushbutton_remove.hide()
        self.pushbutton_pause.hide()
        
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self, item):
        try:
            self.pushbutton_stop.show()
            self.pushbutton_pause.show()
            
            pygame.init()
            name = item.text() + '.mp3'
            pygame.mixer.music.load(name)
            pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        except Exception:
            self.pushbutton_stop.hide()
            self.pushbutton_pause.hide()
            self.pushbutton_remove.hide()
            print('Error file')
    
    def clickstop(self):
        try:
            self.pushbutton_stop.hide()
            self.pushbutton_pause.hide()
            self.pushbutton_remove.hide()
            
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            pygame.quit()
        except Exception:
            pass
    
    def clickpause(self):
        try:
            self.pushbutton_pause.hide()
            self.pushbutton_remove.show()
            
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        except Exception:
            pass
    
    def clickremove(self):
        try:
            self.pushbutton_pause.show()
            self.pushbutton_remove.hide()
            
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        except Exception:
            pass
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            pygame.quit()
        except Exception:
            pass
        finally:
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Можно ссылки на документации или гайды которые помогут лучше разобраться в теме?

Comment: Можно изучить здесь: https://python-scripts.com/pyqt5

Comment: И здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/