# mp3 player, проблема с кнопкой "следующая песня"

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Не могу нормально прописать функцию переключения на следующий трек, вытащил название трека который должен проигрываться, но заставить его играть не получается.

```
    def play(self):
    self.item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
    if self.item:
        self.file_name = os.path.join(self.dir, self.item.text())
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.file_name))

        self.mp3_player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.mp3_player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.mp3_player.play()
    else:
        self.listWidget.setCorrentRow(0)
        self.play()

def stop(self):
    self.mp3_player.stop()

def load(self):
    self.listWidget.clear()
    self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory")
    if dir:
        for file_name in os.listdir(self.dir):
            if file_name.endswith(".mp3"):
                self.listWidget.addItem(os.path.join(file_name))
        self.dir = self.dir

def next(self):
    self.tracks = os.listdir(self.dir)
    track = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
    next_track_index = self.tracks.index(track) + 1
    next_track = self.tracks[next_track_index]

    

def previous(self):
    print("Previous")
```

Comment: ну так а где там строчка, которая должна проигрывать трек?

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038037/pyqt5-qmediaplayer-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba/1038204#1038204 на ваш вопрос ?