# PyQt5 синхронизация музыки со временем python3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Уже есть GUI с self.horizontalSlider. Нужно слайдер синхронизировать с временем музыки, и возможность перетягивать ползуков в нужный момент времени играние музыки. Спасибо!

Еще подскажите элемент управления в PyQt Designer, связанный со временем. Чтобы как раз это время синхронизовать с ползунком и самой музыкой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038037/qmediaplayer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba/1038204#1038204